# NextJs Stripe Subscription with subscription end date

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I have generated some products in stripe configured as recurring payment and i can subscribe to them without problem.
I would like to know if it is possible from the same call that is made to generate the subscription it is possible to indicate the end date of this subscription.
Researching the documentation I see that they talk about "cancel_at" but I can't find where to indicate this parameter in the call. I haven't been able to locate any examples either.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: "price_1LaMHQH4AS5eXWlNhznAR7JA",
            quantity: 1
          },
        ],
       
        mode: 'subscription',
        
        success_url:`${req.headers.origin}/public/payment?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/public/payment?cancelled=true`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide an end date for a Subscription in a Checkout Session.

What you can do instead is to listen for the [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) webhook event. This event will contain the [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=node#checkout_session_object-subscription) id and upon receipt of the event, you can make a request to update that Subscription's [`cancel_at`](https://ttps://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=node#update_subscription-cancel_at).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I look to work with listening to the event. Regardless, it forces a second call to update the subscription. I hope in the future they incorporate that possibility.